# Unable to reuse block of code but not sure what to change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a limited understanding of html, javascript, and css. I have this code below that creates tab content but I can't seem to keep a tab from First Use and a tab from Second Use open at the same time. I have tried changing class names, ids, function names, etc. but this either breaks it or causes it not to work as intended. What do I need to change in the second block so that they work as two separate entities? How can I keep tabs from both uses open at once? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
/* First Use */

<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
   
    border-bottom: 1px solid #727272;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    /* position: relative; */
    /* top: -6px; */
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #727272;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #637dff;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'Section 1')" id="defaultOpen">Hydrogeological Investigations</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'Section 2')">Construction Dewatering</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'Section 3')">Land Development</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'Section 4')">Feature Based Water Balance</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'Section 5')">Environmental Monitoring</button>
</div>

<div id="Section 1" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Hydrogeological Investigations</h3>
  <p>Section 1 Text Here.</p>
<img src="http://watermarkenv.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/groundwater-835827.jpg" style="height: 50%; width: 50%">

<div style="text-align: right"><a href="http://watermarkenv.ca/hydrogeological-services/#web-hg-services"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" style="font-size: 30px"></i></a></div>
</div>

<div id="Section 2" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Construction Dewatering</h3>
  <p>Section 2 text here.</p>

<div style="text-align: right"><a href="http://watermarkenv.ca/hydrogeological-services/#web-hg-services"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" style="font-size: 30px"></i></a></div>  
</div>

<div id="Section 3" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Land Development</h3>
  <p>Section 3 text here.</p>
  
<div style="text-align: right"><a href="http://watermarkenv.ca/hydrogeological-services/#web-hg-services"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" style="font-size: 30px"></i></a></div>
</div>

<div id="Section 4" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Feature Based Water Balance</h3>
  <p>Section 4 text here.</p>
  
<div style="text-align: right"><a href="http://watermarkenv.ca/hydrogeological-services/#web-hg-services"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" style="font-size: 30px"></i></a></div>  
</div>

<div id="Section 5" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Environmental Monitoring</h3>
  <p>Section 5 text here.</p>
  
<div style="text-align: right"><a href="http://watermarkenv.ca/hydrogeological-services/#web-hg-services"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" style="font-size: 30px"></i></a></div>
</div>

<script>
function openSection(evt, sectionName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(sectionName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
     
</body>
</html> 

/* Second Use */

<html>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'Section 1 env')" id="defaultOpenenv">Blah</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'Section 2 env')">Blah</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'Section 3 env')">Blah</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'Section 4 env')">Blah</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'Section 5 env')">Blah</button>
</div>

<div id="Section 1 env" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Hydrogeological Investigations</h3>
  <p>Section 1 Text Here. Second Use</p>
<img src="http://watermarkenv.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/groundwater-835827.jpg" style="height: 50%; width: 50%">

<div style="text-align: right"><a href="http://watermarkenv.ca/hydrogeological-services/#web-hg-services"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" style="font-size: 30px"></i></a></div>
</div>

<div id="Section 2 env" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Construction Dewatering</h3>
  <p>Section 2 text here.</p>

<div style="text-align: right"><a href="http://watermarkenv.ca/hydrogeological-services/#web-hg-services"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" style="font-size: 30px"></i></a></div>  
</div>

<div id="Section 3 env" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Land Development</h3>
  <p>Section 3 text here.</p>
  
<div style="text-align: right"><a href="http://watermarkenv.ca/hydrogeological-services/#web-hg-services"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" style="font-size: 30px"></i></a></div>
</div>

<div id="Section 4 env" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Feature Based Water Balance</h3>
  <p>Section 4 text here.</p>
  
<div style="text-align: right"><a href="http://watermarkenv.ca/hydrogeological-services/#web-hg-services"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" style="font-size: 30px"></i></a></div>  
</div>

<div id="Section 5 env" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Environmental Monitoring</h3>
  <p>Section 5 text here.</p>
  
<div style="text-align: right"><a href="http://watermarkenv.ca/hydrogeological-services/#web-hg-services"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" style="font-size: 30px"></i></a></div>
</div>

<script>
function openSection(evt, sectionName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(sectionName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpenenv").click();
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well java and javascript are not the same thing. ;)

Comment: What is the code you tried that did not work? You said you change the names, looks the same to me.

Comment: You could use bootstrap navigation tabs to make it easier https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do but you can reuse your css classes and javascript functions all over the place, you dont have to write all that stuff twice (which is kind of the point). Just make sure `id` attributes are unique in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

You need unique `id's` for this to work. When you click the tab with id `Section 2` in the second use, it will open the tab content for `Section 2` in the first use.